# how to combine two tables in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

using Sql server 2008 I can return two table results like the below
[BOTH TABLE CONTAIN SAME DATA AND SIMILAR DATA AS WELL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmaFR.jpg)

I'm trying to combine these two tables and eliminate the repeated data by comparing PK[PrimaryKeys] to get the result like the above.

But I dunno how to do this, can anyone help me out here, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell me you did not screen shot production data

Comment: Simply t1 union t2

Comment: @Andrew no its my homework

Comment: So your teacher did screen shot of production data ?!?

Comment: @Veljko89 its from my text book.

Comment: @Andrew can you help me with this?

Comment: @sridhar Combine two tables using Left join on key Column Payid

Comment: @Sridar - Jayasurya, has provided an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a UNION and the duplicates will be automatically removed (For Duplicates for all All Columns)

```
INSERT INTO Table3
(
    PayId,
    PayName,
    PayMail,
    PayPhone
)
SELECT
        PayId,
        PayName,
        PayMail,
        PayPhone
        FROM Table1 

    UNION

    SELECT
        PayId,
        PayName,
        PayMail,
        PayPhone
        FROM Table2
```

Or if you want to Remove the duplicates only based on PayId. try This

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        PayId,
        PayName,
        PayMail,
        PayPhone
        FROM Table1 

    UNION

    SELECT
        PayId,
        PayName,
        PayMail,
        PayPhone
        FROM Table2
),C2
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PayId),
        PayId,
        PayName,
        PayMail,
        PayPhone
        FROM CTE
)
INSERT INTO Table3
(
    PayId,
    PayName,
    PayMail,
    PayPhone
)
SELECT
    PayId,
    PayName,
    PayMail,
    PayPhone
    FROM C2
        WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Technically, the union will only remove exact duplicate rows, not rows which match on primary key, but mismatch on other values. It's not clear in his scenario if the PK is all columns or not and whether there could be a difference. The OP does specify comparing PK's, which is not what the union will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
;With Table1(Payid,PayName,Paymail,Payphone)
AS
(
SELECT 'MK1234000','John','j40@YPRO.com',1222121        UNION ALL
SELECT 'MK1234002','Brown','BLACKPAI@AC.com',4444455    UNION ALL
SELECT 'MK1234003','GINGER','GK202@YPRO.com',8938343    UNION ALL
SELECT 'MK1234004','LINDA','LACYGIRL@VV.com',8938349    UNION ALL
SELECT 'MK1234008','ANDAN','ANDAN.HR@KYP.com',8938349
)
,Table2(Payid,PayName,Paymail,Payphone)
AS
(
SELECT 'MK1234000','John','j40@YPRO.com',1222121        UNION ALL
SELECT 'MK1234002','Brown','BLACKPAI@AC.com',4444455    UNION ALL
SELECT 'MK1234003','GINGER','GK202@YPRO.com',8938343    UNION ALL
SELECT 'MK1234004','LINDA','LACYGIRL@VV.com',8938349    UNION ALL
SELECT 'MK1234008','ANDAN','ANDAN.HR@KYP.com',8938349   UNION ALL
SELECT 'MK1234009','SAROK','SSKK@Gmail.com',87436222    UNION ALL
SELECT 'MK1234022','YUTHI','YUTHI@Hg.com',92473433
)

SELECT B.* 
FROM Table2 B LEFT JOIN Table1 A
On A.Payid=B.Payid
```

Expected Result

```
Payid       PayName  Paymail            Payphone
-------------------------------------------------
MK1234000   John    j40@YPRO.com        1222121
MK1234002   Brown   BLACKPAI@AC.com     4444455
MK1234003   GINGER  GK202@YPRO.com      8938343
MK1234004   LINDA   LACYGIRL@VV.com     8938349
MK1234008   ANDAN   ANDAN.HR@KYP.com    8938349
MK1234009   SAROK   SSKK@Gmail.com      87436222
MK1234022   YUTHI   YUTHI@Hg.com        92473433
```

Comment: what if i've 1232 row ,73 col?. any another way to do it?